# Cartesian product of reflexive spaces is reflexive

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Given $(E,\|\|_E),(F,\|\|_F)$ reflexive normed vector spaces.
I have to prove that also $(E\times F,\|\|_{E\times F})$ is reflexive where $\|\|_{E\times F}$ is the product norm.

What I know is that $(E\times F)'$ is algebrically and topologically isomorphic to $E'\times F'$.

Comment: search over the site this question has already been answered

Comment: Can you post the link of that question? I can't find it

Comment: @Well, I must confess I've not found it, but you should look at [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/664545/how-to-prove-x-times-y-is-a-isometric-isomorphism-of-x-times-y).

Answer (score 5):

Let $J:(E'\times F')\to (E\times F)'$ be defined by $(J(e,f))(x,y)=e(x)+f(y)$. [We know that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/664545/how-to-prove-x-times-y-is-a-isometric-isomorphism-of-x-times-y)
$$J(E'\times F')=(E\times F)'.\tag{$*$}$$

Take a bounded sequence $(x_n,y_n)$ in $E\times F$. Then $(x_n)$ is bounded in $E$ and $(y_n)$ is bounded in $F$. Since $E$ and $F$ are reflexive, there are subsequences $(x_{n_k})$, $(y_{n_k})$ and vectors $x\in E$, $y\in F$ such that
$$x_{n_k}\rightharpoonup x\text{ in }E,\quad y_{n_k}\rightharpoonup y\text{ in }F$$
and thus
$$(J(e,f))(x_{n_k},y_{n_k})=e(x_{n_k})+f(y_{n_k})\to e(x)+f(y)=(J(e,f))(x,y),\quad\forall\;(e,f)\in E'\times F'.$$
It follows from $(*)$ that
$$g(x_{n_k},y_{n_k})\to g(x,y),\quad \forall\; g\in (E\times F)'$$
and thus

$$(x_{n_k},y_{n_k})\rightharpoonup (x,y)\text{ in }E\times F.$$

This shows that every bounded sequence in $E\times F$ admits a weakly convergent subsequence. So, by the Eberlein-Šmulian theorem, $E\times F$ is reflexive.