# Prove the space is $X\times Y $ is reflective

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Suppose $X,Y$ are reflective Banach spaces. Let $Z=X\times Y$. The norm is defined as $$\|z\|=(\|x\|^p+\|y\|^p)^{\frac{1}{p}},\forall z=(x,y) \in X\times Y$$
here, $1\leq p\leq \infty$.
Prove that $Z$ is reflective.

This is my functional analysis homework.
And my idea is below:

$\forall F \in X^{**},\exists x\in X,s.t.F(f)=f(x), \forall f \in X^*$

$\forall G \in Y^{**},\exists y\in Y,s.t.G(g)=g(y), \forall g \in Y^*$

Now I want to prove $\forall H\in(X\times Y)^{**}, \exists z\in (X\times Y),s.t.H(h)=h(z),\forall h \in (X\times Y)^{*}$
(Another idea is to prove $\phi(X)=X^{**}$ directly, where $\phi$ is the canonical mapping)

And my problem is:How to use the condition that  $X,Y$ are reflective Banach spaces?  what's the relationship between $(X,Y)^{**}$ and $X^{**},Y^{**}$?

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: You could see the following link: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/831791/cartesian-product-of-reflexive-spaces-is-reflexive